# how to print a count of the amount of core data binary images

Tags: swift, core-data, count, attributes, binary-data

In my swift code below the goal is to print the number of items in the a core data attribute. Right now what is being printed out is not making sense to me. What is being printed out is 413091 and it should be 1. I assume that its printing out a number of how core data binary is saved but it should be 1 photo saved 1 item stored and print  just 1.

[image: core data image]

[image: what is printing out in debugg section]

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let gwen = UIImage(named: "a.jpeg")
        if let imageData = gwen.self?.pngData() {
            DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveImage(data: imageData)
        }
        
        let arr = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImage()
        let jake = Int()
        print("core data number is : ", arr[jake].img!.count)
        
        
    }
    
}


class DataBaseHelper {
    
    static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func saveImage(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = Image(context: context)
        imageInstance.img = data
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Image is saved")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchImage() -> [Image] {
        var fetchingImage = [Image]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Image")
        
        do {
            fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Image]
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching the image")
        }
        
        return fetchingImage
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr[jake].img` that's a `Data` object. So you are printing its size. It should be the same as `imageData.count`

Comment: to count the number of images, just use: `print("core data number is : ", arr.count)`.